# Is there possible to print a message in a zend controller function, without using a view?

Tags: php, ajax, string, zend-framework

I don't know if this question is duplicated or not. I'm a totally newbie in zend. I want to use an ajax event and when i call the controllername/myfunctionfromthecontroller in url , i want to return a message . I tried this :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/location/testare",
    type: "POST",
    data: post_array,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        //data - response from server
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    }
});
```

and in the controller :

```
public function testareAction()
{ 
    $this->view->String = 'hello world';
}
```

the firebu return me this : "500 Internal Server Error". Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: I'm using zf1 version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this in Zend Framework 1. MaiKaY's solution seems to be fore ZF2:

In the **controller**, before the output, set the header to expose json output:

```
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Disable all the layout stuff:

```
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
```

And if you want to use `echo \Zend_Json::encode($yourOutput);` instead of using a view for the json, use this:

```
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
```

Comment: can you be more specific please, you know , you know this is the first time when i see zend. can you give me more explanation, i really appreciate it

Comment: and this will return what message ?

Comment: can is set my type in jquery to json ?

Comment: @Chester Yes in jQuery JSON is good. It will return JSON encoded output

Comment: thx man , you save me from a lot of searching on the internet

Comment: the jsonModel will do the same without the many code lines :)

Comment: @MaiKaY JsonModel is not available in ZF1 !! "many code lines", it's 2-3 lines of code, dude, did you downvote my answer?

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to use the [jsonModel](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/returning-json-from-a-zf2-controller-action/)

it looks like

```
public function testareAction()
{
    return new JsonModel(array(
        'message' => 'hello world',
    ));
}
```

Comment: im getting this in firebug : "500 Internal Server Error". by the way i dont want to use the index function :)

Comment: ... rename the function? ^^

Answer (score 0):

Use helpers!

Example:

If you want to return string using json:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  dataType: 'json',
  ...
});
```

And in controller:

```
public function testareAction() 
{
    $this->_helper->json('hello world');
}
```

That's all!

More [Zend Framework Helper Json](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.json)